# Restricting usercontrol from moving beyond the canvas xaml

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am developing Windows 8.1 Store Apps using XAML.

The scenario is I am having a Canvas in which I am placing more than one user controls. The user controls can be moved on click of a button. I should restrict the user controls from moving beyond the Canvas. What is the way to do it.? I am having Manipulation events within the usercontrol for movement.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your controls that you move are children from the canvas?
If so i think you can do a check to see if the bounds of you control moving on your canvas hits the border of you canvas. If this is happening then make it stop.

Basic gameprogramming stuff. I will look for a example

Comment: Ya. The controls are children from the canvas. The user control have events like ManipulationStarted, ManipulationDelta and ManipulationCompleted to handle the movement. The problem is I dont know how to check the bounds of Canvas while Movement.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

This part of code will get you the place of your control inside your container

```
public static class BoundsHelper
{
    public static Rect GetBoundsInParentContainer(Control control)
    {
        Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(control);
        Rect rect = new Rect(offset.X, offset.Y, control.ActualHeight, control.ActualWidth);
        return rect;
    }
}
```

So if you have a button in the top left corner of the canvas and you ask that button the control where it is it will give you a rect where the X and Y are 0 and the Width and Height  of your control. So if you move your control inside your canvas. Call this method and check if your control is still inside the Height and width of your canvas.

Here the code to move to the right but first check if you are allowed to move

```
private void MoveRightAndCheck(Rect boundsControl, Control container)
    {
        int stepSize = 10;

        if (container.ActualWidth > (boundsControl.X + boundsControl.Width + stepSize))
        {
            //Your code to move your control inside the canvas
        }
    }
```